# VSCode closes immediately after opening

Tags: visual-studio-code, registry

My VSCode keeps closing immediately when opened, I can't define the exact cause but this started to come around after I did some changes in my registry to fix my memory usage issues. The following keys are the keys that I modified when I was fixing my memory issue, I don't know if any of these caused the problem.

**Modified Registry Keys:**
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management -> ClearPageFileAtShutdown`
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management -> DisablePagingExecutive`
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management -> LargeSystemCache`
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management -> NonPagedPoolSize`
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management -> PagedPoolSize`
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management -> PhysicalAddressExtension`
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management -> SessionPoolSize`
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management -> SessionViewSize`

**How my vsc problem looks like:**
[vsc problem preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEZOK.gif)

I reinstalled the app several twice and searched for solutions but no luck.

----- Edit 1 -----

After executing `code` in the command prompt, it logged the following:

```
 1: 00007FF6E3472EE6 node::Buffer::New+50054
 2: 00007FF6E3462D33 node::InitializeNodeWithArgs+2371
 3: 00007FF6E1BB77E9 std::__1::__vector_base<v8::CpuProfileDeoptFrame,std::__1::allocator<v8::CpuProfileDeoptFrame> >::__end_cap+22297
 4: 00007FF6E19EECCE std::__1::vector<v8::CpuProfileDeoptInfo,std::__1::allocator<v8::CpuProfileDeoptInfo> >::vector<v8::CpuProfileDeoptInfo,std::__1::allocator<v8::CpuProfileDeoptInfo> >+49406
 5: 00007FF6E54869A2 Cr_z_crc32+4171922
 6: 00007FFFCA8826BD BaseThreadInitThunk+29
 7: 00007FFFCBDCDFB8 RtlUserThreadStart+40
```

----- Edit 2 -----

Somehow, I got it back working. All I did was delete the folder `C:\Users\Me\.vscode`, what is the reason that this fixed it?

Comment: Open Powershell/Command Prompt/Terminal, type `code` to start VS Code and see if you get an error message there. Then [edit] your question and add those message.